App Engine says "Your runtime version for ruby33 is past End of Support", but it isn't
As written in google documentation here and here
I use the latest runtime of Ruby available in app engine.



Runtime
Environment
Runtime ID
End of support
Deprecated
Decommission




Ruby 3.3
Ubuntu 22.04
ruby33
2027-03-31
2028-03-31



Ruby 3.2
Ubuntu 22.04
ruby32
2026-03-31
2027-03-31




My worker.yml starts like that:
runtime: ruby33
env: flex
service: default
entrypoint: bundle exec sidekiq
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 1.6
  disk_size_gb: 10

My Gemfile starts like so:
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "3.3.1"

My Gemfile.lock ends like that:
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.3.1p55

BUNDLED WITH
   2.3.26

My Dockerfile starts like that:
# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.3.1
FROM registry.docker.com/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

My cloudbuild.yaml looks like that
#First I build the image:
  - id: "Build worker"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    script: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      docker build --target worker -t $_IMAGE_URL .

#Then I deploy it:
 - id: "Launch worker"
   name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine'
   script: |
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     gcloud app deploy worker.yaml --image-url=$_IMAGE_URL --quiet

but when deploying, I get this error:

Step #13 - "Launch worker": ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Your runtime version for ruby33 is past End of Support. Please upgrade to the latest runtime version available..

I have no idea how to fix it. Can you help me?

I cannot see the operating system in your  worker.yaml file? Also it is not recommended to specifically add the ruby runtime version number. Also I tried to deploy a simple Hello World app by following this Document and successfully deployed without any errors.

Try to deploy your service again using the --verbosity=debug flag and see the result. Also make sure that you are using the latest version of Goolge cloud SDK.

I am not sure if it matters as I don't use this but ruby:3.3.1-slim is based on Debian 12.6 "Bookworm" but then you show Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) compatibility.

If you use App Engine Flex, look at the flex page (replace "standard" with "flexible" in the URL of your links). And try it again: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime
That being said, to run a container at scale, Cloud Run is a far better place than App Engine flex.

@guillaumeblaquiere Sure. But it is too much of a hassle to run a process that doesn't respond to http requests on Cloud Run.

It seems the way the yaml file is processed by app engine has slightly changed between July 4th 2024 and August 8th 2024.
Now runtime_config.operating_system MUST be defined or it will fail with the unclear error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error(s) encountered validating runtime. Your runtime version for ...
I fixed this issue by adding this to my worker.yml file:
runtime: ruby
env: flex
service: default
entrypoint: bundle exec sidekiq
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22" # <-- FIX

#...

